# Is the smallest usable memory size 2 bytes, In javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, memory-management, character-encoding

To represent a single character in JS, we use `"` or `'`, i.e use a string of length 1.

But since [JavaScript uses the UTF-16 encoding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4), the character would be 16 bit as well.

Would it be safe to thus say, 2 bytes is the smallest re presentable size, that is possible in JS.

Or would there be some data structure, which can represent a single byte (8 bit) which I am missing.

**EDIT:**

I understand using the datatype with word size (usually 4 bytes) is always the most efficient, but I just wondered if the creators of JS would have cared to include something in.

Actionscript 3 derives from ECMAScript as well & it includes a variable size data type i.e an integer in AS3 is 1 to 4 bytes of storage.

Note : I'm not really looking for a hack to fit in multiple bytes into a larger datatype.

Guess the answer is most probably **no**.

Comment: There is no ECMAScript value that is defined to be/store "8 bits" of information. Furthermore, using a numeric instead of a string of a single character is likely more efficient as strings also must contain the length and may not be subject to the same object elision optimizations (which is an implementation detail).

Comment: What is the smallest representable size exactly? Remember that any variable can hold _any_ value, you cannot limit a variable to hold just one character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not in ECMAScript but in node.js you have [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) and in browsers you have [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Uint8Array)

```
var b = new UInt8Array(16); //Holds 16 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can have an array of 8 [booleans](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.3) - but there might be significant overhead in storing the array itself.

Comment: Yes, but you can treat them as such, and test using `=== true`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a page from c-style unions, sure, you can create your own data structure which does just that. Using a large int as a bitmap.

```
var memory = 0;

function setbyte(addr, value) {
    memory = memory | (value << addr);
}

function getbyte(addr) {
    return 0xFF & (memory>>addr)
}
```

Comment: Yes but you're storing multiple values in it.

Comment: "Would it be safe to thus say, 2 bytes is the smallest re presentable size, that is possible in JS. Or would there be some data structure, which can represent a single byte (8 bit) which I am missing."

Comment: I guess the answer is no, but this is a fun exercise.

Comment: Warning: this does not scale well to very large numbers because all numbers in JavaScript are floating point. Also, I believe the constant should be `0xFF`.

Comment: Correct, constant is changed to FF. Thanks.